# I optimized this code but it's still weird. Can someone help me take a look?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have a piece of code like this: it has two judgment conditions. One is validate minSelection and rhe other is validate MaxSelection。

```
//  minSelectValidate
        const minSelectionError = minSelection &&
          (Array.isArray(v)
            ? v?.length < minSelection
            : values(v).some((item) => item.length < minSelection));

        if (minSelectionError) {
          return Promise.reject(
            new Error(
              formatMessage(
                {
                  id: 'pages.edit.question.min.selection',
                  defaultMessage: `此题最少要选择 ${minSelection} 个选项`,
                },
                { selection: minSelection },
              ),
            ),
          )
        }

        // maxSelectValidate
        const maxSelectionError = maxSelection && Array.isArray(v)
          ? v?.length > maxSelection
          : values(v).some((item) => item.length > maxSelection);

        if (maxSelectionError) {
          return Promise.reject(
            new Error(
              formatMessage(
                {
                  id: 'pages.edit.question.max.selection',
                  defaultMessage: `此题最多可选择 ${maxSelection} 个选项`,
                },
                { selection: maxSelection },
              ),
            ),
          )
        }
      }
```

Then I changed it to this:

```
const validates = {
    hasMinSelection(value: any, minSelection: number) {
      if (Array.isArray(value)) return value?.length < minSelection
      return values(value).some((item) => item.length < minSelection)
    },
    hasMaxSelection(value: any, maxSelection: number) {
      if (Array.isArray(value)) return value?.length > maxSelection
      return values(value).some((item) => item.length > maxSelection)
    }
  }
```

But I feel that these two methods are still very similar. Is there any other good way to optimize it?

Save the child QAQ

Comment: Never over optimise at the expense of readability and maintainability of the code - look at your final code, look at the answer below ... which is easier to understand?

Comment: So you're not trying to optimise performance, but to avoid code duplication?

Comment: "*I changed it to this*" - what happened to the promise rejections and the elaborate error messages? Much more code duplication in there.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a function version of `<` and `>`, and then you can use the conditional operator to alternate between those two functions, depending on an argument.

```
const lessThan = (x, y) => x < y;
const greaterThan = (x, y) => x > y;
const validates = {
    hasMinOrMaxSelection(value: any, selection: number, hasMin: boolean) {
        const fn = hasMin ? lessThan : greaterThan;
        if (Array.isArray(value)) return fn(value?.length, selection);
        return values(value).some((item) => fn(item.length, selection));
    }
}
```

Then have the third argument be true (for a `hasMinSelection` check) or false (for a `hasMaxSelection` check).

Comment: While technically this could be correct, I would argue that this harms the readability of the code :p

Comment: Completely fair, over-abstraction sometimes *feels* more elegant due to DRY-ness but may not be worth it

Comment: Not taking anything away from the answer though - to be clear